# Overlays; how to turn off grid display only?

Tags: 3d-view

I have tried to turn off the grid in the overlay options, but when I went to check it off, it was already unchecked.  However, the grid is still displayed!

The only way I know of to turn it off is to totally turn off overlays, but that turns off all of them, and I don't want to do that.  Can someone help me out?

**Edit:**
I noticed that the grid check box is greyed out, so what now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide grid floor and axis, using viewport overlay options:

[image]

The "grid" option is for "orthographic side view' (from the tooltip):

[image]

Comment: thanks!  Don't know what the gird is about.